# Create folder templates in theme Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Normally, I would create the file:

```
single-{post-type}.php
header-{template}.php
page-{template}.php...
```

in my folder theme.

But I want to all template files into one folder "templates", What is the solution, somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Perhaps one of the most common is to use [get_template_part()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part#Using_with_theme_subfolders).

Also, it's worth noting that WordPress will search all sub-directories for page templates, by default, [since WordPress 3.4](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#File_Folders). This only refers to custom page templates, however, and does not include specialized page templates.